# OpenVPN on Windows Server 2008 - keeps disconnecting 'from itself'

Tags: openvpn

I have OpenVPN GUI on Windows Server 2008 & can connect fine from a Windows 8 client.

However, after a few hours - whether the client is connected or not - the server disconnects and doesn't reconnect (ie - the VPN becomes unavailable) - and I have to manually 'connect' it . Once I have done that - I can connect again with the client.

How can I stop it going down, and or - get it to reconnect automatically?

Thanks

(I googled this, but it all seemed to be about clients disconnecting from the server - not the server disconnecting 'from itself').

From Log:

```
Tue Jul 23 17:47:51 2013 my-laptop/000.000.000.000:53987 TLS: soft reset sec=0 bytes=68701/0 pkts=889/0
Tue Jul 23 17:48:10 2013 C:\Windows\system32\route.exe DELETE 10.8.0.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.2
Tue Jul 23 17:48:10 2013 Route deletion via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
Tue Jul 23 17:48:10 2013 Closing TUN/TAP interface
Tue Jul 23 17:48:10 2013 SIGTERM[hard,] received, process exiting
Tue Jul 23 17:48:10 2013 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1374598090,EXITING,SIGTERM,,
```

(IP removed for security reasons)

It appears to disconnect shortly after the client disconnects. I would like the OpenVPN server - on the server - to stay up 24/7

Comment: Did you inspect the Event Log or [the custom OpenVPN log files](http://www.surfbouncer.com/OpenVPN_logs.htm)?

Comment: Have updated question